# Join in inside and outside subquery

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I am working with 3 tables sales, customer & product where I want to get all columns from the sales table and customer_name, customer age from customer table and product_name, category from the product table in the same result set. There's a condition that I have to use 2 join operations where one join will be inside subquery and the other outside subquery.
Here's my query that's not working:

```
 SELECT a.*,
    b.customer_name,
    b.age, 
    b.customer_id 
 FROM sales AS a
 LEFT JOIN customer AS b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, product_name, category from product) as c
    ON a.product_id = c.product_id
 ORDER BY a.customer_id, b.customer_id;
```

Only the first join is working in this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
a.*,
b.customer_name,
b.age, 
b.customer_id ,
c.*
from sales as a
left join customer as b
on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, product_name, category from product) as c
ON a.product_id = c.product_id
order by a.customer_id;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wKbMaD6UF1v3a4KCXE7248/0

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the product_id column twice.